# Python MySQL query more than one join

Tags: python, mysql

I want to join several tables with each other. The database connection is established and I'm getting this error :

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
import numpy as np

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = "n.neshat",
                                         passwd = "Start123", 
                                         db = "base",
                                         host="192.168.126.29")
cursor = cnx.cursor()

test = ("select * from projects\ 
        join positions\ on projects.id  = positions.project_id\
        join loads\ on positions.id = loads.position_id\
        join equipments\ on positions.id = equipments.position_id\
        join module_fields\ on positions.id = module_fields.position_id\
        join configurations\ on positions.id = configurations.position_id\
        join module_blocks\ on configurations.id = module_blocks.configuration_id")

cursor.execute(test)

myresult = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: I'm getting this mistake: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Did you try to reformat the string?

Comment: I don't know what the error is when I make the query in the database it works, however the same query doesn't work in python

Comment: In which line does the error occur? When an error occurs, always try to understand the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid unintended SQL syntax typos, I recommend using Python's multiline syntax.  And also, use aliases:

```
test = """SELECT * FROM projects pr
          INNER JOIN positions po ON pr.id  = po.project_id
          INNER JOIN loads l ON po.id = l.position_id
          INNER JOIN equipments e ON po.id = e.position_id
          INNER JOIN module_fields mf ON po.id = mf.position_id
          INNER JOIN configurations c ON po.id = c.position_id
          INNER JOIN module_blocks mb ON c.id = mb.configuration_id"""
```

Answer (score 2):

use `"""` for multilines string :

```py
test = """select * from projects
        join positions on projects.id  = positions.project_id
        join loads on positions.id = loads.position_id
        join equipments on positions.id = equipments.position_id
        join module_fields on positions.id = module_fields.position_id
        join configurations on positions.id = configurations.position_id
        join module_blocks on configurations.id = module_blocks.configuration_id"""
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is still better than mine :)